# System.StringException: Invalid id: for a lookup field value

Tags: apex, id, invalid

Following are the 2 lines of my controller code,

```
system.debug('id is ' + FSInputRecord.Client__c);
if(FSInputRecord.Client__c != null && FSInputRecord.Client__c != '')
```

Where `FSInputRecord.Client__c` is a lookup to Contact which gets its value from the VF page.

Now the first line gives me a valid ID e.g. `00355000009YTSrAAO`
But the second line throws exception - System.StringException: Invalid id:

Why so? what is the problem with the ID here?

Also when I leave the `FSInputRecord.Client__c` input lookup field empty then the second line doesn't throw any error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Client__c is of the Id type, the empty string ('') is being coerced to an Id, which is not a valid Id. You never need to compare an Id to an empty string, because that is not a valid state for an Id to be in. The error doesn't occur when Client__c is null, because the && operator is a short-circuit operator (if the left side is false, the right side is never evaluated).

Comment: I believe I'm reading it incorrectly, did you mean "if the left side is **false** , the right side is never evaluated"? Just confused...

Comment: @Mahmood Oops. You're right. That's what I meant. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of this `FSInputRecord.Client__c != '`'.Can you try removing this and see if this solves your problem.Let us know if the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Check this post from Deepak Anand, explains why Empty Strings throw an error for ID.

EMPTY STRING - eventhought it doesn't have any value but an EMPTY STRING 
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hTOsAAM